# phpMyAdmin won't load

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm trying to open my PhpMyAdmin by using this address because my port in xampp is 8080.

> http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/

But the page won't load and after a while, it will give time out error.
In my config.inc file,

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '1234';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost:8080';
```

what i did so far was changing

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';'
```

and changing

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost:8080';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

as well as changing my password to ' ' but still no luck

Answer (score 2):

If you use XAMPP, there should be a way to open phpMyAdmin directly from the XAMPP interface. I suggest you revert the changes you've made to config.inc.php and try using the XAMPP method to enter.

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';

I thought XAMPP uses auth_type config, so this is a bit strange; you mention changing *from* http *to* config, but may it have been set to config in the first place? Stating the username and password (as is done on the next two lines) is only needed with auth_type config, so if you're using some other method those lines are ignored.

Furthermore, using 'http' doesn't give as great of error reporting if a problem occurs when logging in; for testing purposes please try using 'config' or 'cookie' and see if you get a better error back.

That being said, if you're just getting a blank page after a long time trying to load, that suggests that something else might be wrong. Check your webserver error log for hints about what the problem could be.

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost:8080';

This is certainly incorrect; as this directive specifies the hostname for the MySQL server and you would specify the MySQL port number with `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']`. Probably `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';` is correct here, and the comment above stating that it's connecting via TCP (instead of socket) would support that guess.